# Magento 2 create module block

Tags: magento2, php, module, javascript, extensions

I want to define a new phtml block in the head of my module: I try to add something like this in my `app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Custom\Module\Block\Hello" name="mycustom" template="Custom_Module::mycustom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

the phtml file must be loaded in the head and in the phtml file I have only a small javascript that will call a slider.

```
$('.slideshow').banner({image :"images/slide1.png"});
```

How I can create `Custom\Module\Block\Hello` block and what must contain this file?

Thank you

UPDATE:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">       
    require([
        'jquery', 
        'banner'
    ], function($, banner){
        $(function(){
           $(document).banner({});
        })
    });
</script> 



<div class="snowme">Text me</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create Custom module block with at least contain this code(**Path:** `app\code\Custom\Module\Block`):

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Block;

class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Add below script into your phtml file to call slider js:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">       
    require([
        'jquery', 
        'banner'
    ], function($, banner){
        $(function(){
            $('.slideshow').banner({image :"images/slide1.png"});       
        })
    });
</script>
```

Define requirejs-config.js file contains below code:

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
         'banner': "Custom_Module/js/sliderjs.js"
      },   
    shim: {
        'banner': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
}
```

Add your js file into `view/frontend/web/js` folder.

Note: If you have error like "**jquery is not a function**" add below code into your js

```
require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      //banner js code
    });  
});
```

Comment: thank you that js is not work very well I read and must be declared like this:

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
    jQuery(document).banner(

Comment: you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: Block issue or js declaration issue?

Comment: I really don't know I think is a js declaration

Comment: Do you need slider in header part?

Comment: this is not important, in the phtml file in head will be only the javascript

Comment: add some div content in your phtml file and then check it

Comment: the div is okay is there, but my custom javascript is not loaded, I have the error is not a function

Comment: jquery is not a function. this is the error right?

Comment: yes indeed please take a look I update my post to see the entire javascript code

Comment: Check update answer. add extra code into your banner js

Comment: thank you so much for your help, is the same, maybe there we need to add some noconflict? is the default luma theme

Comment: Yes, You have to use Parent as Luma theme for your custom theme. but yes, I had same issue which resolved using my code.

Comment: if I use your last code for javascript my custom js file is not loaded anymore

Comment: I solved I add here require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'] this 'banner' and everything seems to work okay now, thank you very much for your help

Comment: is there anything  extra you did except my  solution?

Comment: I add this 'banner' here in this code: require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], so the final code will look require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui','banner']